# "В свете последних событий" обособляется?

Tags: пунктуация

Обособляется ли запятыми "в свете последних событий"?

Answer (score 2):

Оба варианта возможны. Всё зависит от желания автора **выделить обстоятельственный оборот** и от **структуры** самого предложения.

**1) Примеры:**

Эта информация не является на 100% точной и взята из публикаций в интернете, но, на мой взгляд, **в свете последних событий**, становится достаточно вероятной. [Финансовый кризис и как нас это коснется (форум) (2008)]

...но наши цены растут, а не падают, **в свете последних событий** (= что связано с последними событиями).

― Эта тема действительно актуальна **в свете последних событий**. [Алексей Буланов, Сергей Жвачкин. На голову выше // «Эксперт», 2015]

**2) Пояснение**

**Это обстоятельственный оборот**, который может быть обособленным или необособленным.

**Обособление делается** в том случае, когда оборот находится в удобной позиции. Тогда он **не вписывается в структуру предложения и  не имеет присловного управления.** 
По смыслу оборот в этом случае соответствует  **придаточному предложению:** *если рассматривать что-то в свете последних событий* или  *что связано с последними событиями*.

**3) Примечание**

**Обособленный оборот не является вводным словом,** так как **не относится к тематике вводных слов**. Но неверно было бы думать, что обособляются только вводные слова.

Обособление обстоятельств ― это специальная тема, которая подробно разбирается у Розенталя.

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=114#pp114

Comment: Sharon: Эта информация не является на 100% точной и … (**форум**) (2008) === В развёрнутом виде цитата от этого nick'а с форума выглядит так:  _[**Машустик, nick**] …Только **неизвестно потом** эти кредиты во что переведут, если доллара как такового не будет. Эта информация не является на 100% точной и взята из публикаций в интернете, но, на мой взгляд, в свете последних событий, становится достаточно вероятной_.  Да и второй пример у Вас какой-то не по-русски сказанный… **Ну нельзя же на такие примеры опираться!**

Comment: Это просто примеры, я на них НЕ ОПИРАЮСЬ. Есть правила, которые регламентируют обособление обстоятельств, я опираюсь на НИХ. И мне неясно, зачем Вы уточняете цитаты, можно взять упрощенный вариант: "Эта информация не является точной и взята из публикаций в интернете, но, в свете последних событий, становится достаточно вероятной".  Что здесь нерусского? Здесь явная АКТУАЛИЗАЦИЯ оборота (=если рассматривать её в свете последних событий). Можно самим придумать примеры из любой области (науки, политики, обычной жизни), где этот оборот может быть обособленным или необособленным обстоятельством.

Comment: Да можно взять практически любое предложение с необособленным обстоятельством,  распространить его,   изменить порядок слов, и тогда оборот будет обособляться, например: Эта тема действительно актуальна в свете последних событий. - Тема эта, в свете последних событий,  в настоящий момент становится действительно актуальной.

Comment: Sharon: И мне неясно, зачем Вы уточняете цитаты... === Только для того, чтобы показать, что у этого nick'а полно ошибок в написании сообщений,и потому рекомендовать его пунктуацию  кому бы то ни было вряд ли полезно. _"...Но, **на мой взгляд, в свете последних событий**, становится достаточно вероятной."_ По-моему, очень коряво.

Comment: Мне этот автор незнаком, и я не отвечаю за его грамотность, я просто привожу примеры из Нацкорпуса.  Здесь важен не стиль, а СМЫСЛ. Оборот можно актуализировать, обособив его и придав ему дополнительное обстоятельственное значение, но для этого нужна подходящая структура предложения. И такая необходимость у авторов бывает, что видно из примеров, пусть даже и несовершенных. Но что я уже не понимаю, так это  смысла Ваших вопросов. Вы считаете (даже после всех моих объяснений), что оборот не обособляется НИКОГДА, как указано в предыдущем ответе? Вы бы тоже так ответили?

Comment: _Sharon: Вы считаете (даже после всех моих объяснений), что оборот не обособляется НИКОГДА?_..===  Нет, я так не считаю! Думаю, может обособляться. Но найти  подходящих примеров не сумел. Может, они и существуют... А потому написал бы так: **_практически никогда не обособляется_**.

Comment: А я бы так не написала. Я привела пример, когда  предложение без обособления можно легко перестроить в предложение с обособлением.  Я объяснила смысл такой перестройки (актуализация обстоятельственного значения). Примерно такую же актуализацию дает использование наречия "особенно" (особенно в свете последних событий"). Поэтому я считаю верным данный мною ответ. Если найду походящие примеры, то дополню его (сейчас просто нет времени искать, оборот используется в СМИ, а в этом случае надо, как оказывается, доказывать еще и качество текста).

Comment: @Sharon Я с уверенностью поддерживаю Ваш вывод о возможности обоих случаев, несмотря на то, что вариант вводности в книгах встречается крайне редко. Самым убедительным и **достаточным** аргументом является пункт 4 из Вашего второго ответа (случай "невписываемости" в структуру предложения). Иногда можно вывести наше выражение из числа условий, при условном "свете" которых происходят действия, возникают мнения и т. п., изменив порядок слов так, чтобы это выражение стало отвлечённым штампом, аргументом в пользу всего оставшегося высказывания, намёком на причину изложенного мнения.

Comment: Alex_ander, спасибо за комментарий, я очень ценю Ваше мнение как по этому вопросу, так и по всем другим  темам.

Answer (score 2):

**Учитывая разные мнения, я добавлю еще один обобщенный ответ, чтобы автор вопроса мог лучше разобраться в теме.**

1) Оборот ***в свете последних событий*** является обстоятельственным оборотом со значением соответствия (= с учётом последних событий). **Оборот не является вводным сочетанием**, так как не относится к тематике вводных слов.

2) **Как и все обстоятельства,** выраженные падежной формой существительного, этот оборот **обособляется или не обособляется в соответствии с правилами Розенталя.** Обособление зависит от желания автора выделить обстоятельственный оборот, а также от структуры самого предложения.

3) Практические примеры показывают, что этот оборот чаще встречается **в необособленном виде**, например: *Эта тема действительно актуальна **в свете последних событий**.*

4) Оборот будет обособляться в том случае, если он **явно не вписывается в структуру предложения.** По смыслу обособление оборота связано с его **актуализацией**, то есть с желанием автора подчеркнуть его **значимость**.

5) Примеры обособленного оборота:

*Эта информация не является точной и взята из публикаций в Интернете, но, **в свете последних событи**й, становится достаточно вероятной.*

Здесь авторское обособление (актуализация без перестройки структуры), то есть в данном предложении оборот может и не обособляться.

6) Но необособленный оборот можно обособить, изменив структуру предложения: *Тема эта, **в свете последних событий**, становится теперь действительно актуальной.*

7) Обособляется оборот с наречием ***особенно*** в качестве присоединительного союза: *Сейчас эта тема, **особенно** в свете последних событий, становится действительно актуальной.*

Answer (score 0):

Да нет, не обособляется. Это не вводное сочетание.